# Jekyll kramdown css, text-align works but font-weight doesn't

Tags: css, jekyll, kramdown

I am trying to modify my code block with css. While an example like this works:

````
{: style="text-align: center;"}
```
!! WARNING: TERRIBLE HUMOR AHEAD !!
```
````

[image]

(the text becomes centered inside the code block)
the font weight just refuses to work

````
{: style="text-align: center;  font-weight: 900;"}
```
!! WARNING: TERRIBLE HUMOR AHEAD !!
```
````

How can I make the text inside the code block, bold??

**EDIT:** Final rendered html

[image]

Comment: does `font-weight: bold` work? not all fonts support the 900 ("black") weight.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow oh I tried that first, wasn't working at all

Comment: okay. what about for text that isn't in a code block (surrounded by the triple-backticks)? (just troubleshooting here)

Comment: it would be helpful to see the final HTML markup.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow it works like a charm for other text, even for headings etc

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow edited and added the final rendered html, seems like the `<code>` tag in kramdown is suppressing it, as the html turned out to be fine!

Comment: quick test: does [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/unxkb6rz/) show bold text for you?

Comment: that fiddle does show bold for me. so if you don't see it as bold, it's your browser. if you do, it's a stylesheet interaction with the rest of your website.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow it does show bold for me but I guess kramdown classes are a lot more complex and the `highlighter-rouge` must be overriding it somehow, i

Comment: or as you can say, taking priority over the `<code>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195821/discussion-between-woodrow-barlow-and-ishan-srivastava).